# My jquery sortable and dialog only works in the first DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am creating a check list. This checklist is separated by months. The months are in divs. Each of the div has the same id #projects so that each individual div can sort its #todolist within its month. However, the javascript, ajax and jquery only works in the first div.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#todolist").sortable({axis:"y", containment:"#projects",     
        update: function( event, ui ) {
        updateDisplayOrder();
        }
    });
```

Like wise I created a button where they can add new items to the checklist. This check list also works for the 1st button.

Where did I go wrong? I tried creating new id for each month and it still does'nt work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rule number 1. IDs should be **unique**

Comment: Hi Taylor, I tired changing the ID for all the different divs. It still only works with the first div.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle to show us what you have.

Comment: Also, not related to your problem, but you have 2 ready handlers `$(function()` and  `$(document).ready(` are the same thing

Comment: post your HTML or snippet

Comment: @alexvin since you are using an ID selector, it is only capturing the 1 `div`. You should consider assigning a class to each div and then use the class selector. You'll still have some issue after, but at least it will effect each of the `div`.

Comment: Hey thank you all. I used your comments to solve the problems. Thank you